# Inverse transformation of coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to write this function $$f=f(x(u,v,\theta ),y(u,v,\theta ),z(u,v,\theta ))$$$$x=uvcos\theta \\ y=uvsin\theta \\\\z=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } (u²-v²)$$ inversely, that is:
$$g=g(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),\theta (x,y,z))$$ I've tried isolate u,v and theta but dont worked. Even if it worked, i want to know if exists a method to do this. I am really confused about the name of this process, i "googled" inverse transformation and appeared subjects about linear algebra but this transformation is not linear. Then, I searched for change of parameters and found a pdf in which tell to me write down the chain rule to arrive in the expression above. Then appeared a system of the equations to solve but i didn't continue because i did not know what i've doing. What i really want is to know what is this all about.

Comment: Maybe [this helps.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_coordinates#Three-dimensional_parabolic_coordinates)

Comment: Note that, like many, “polar”-like coordinate systems, this has a singularity at the origin, so you won’t be able to invert there without some convention for what the value of $\theta$ should be.